# IBOutlet is not recognized by Interface Builder when conditioning compiling in Interface declaration  

Tags: iphone, xib, conditional-compilation

If I add this conditioning compiling flag in my header file, which is a owner of a xib file, the xib file cannot read the IBOutlet and show as missing. And gives warnings.

In runtime it works fine. Did anybody experience the same problem?

```
/* MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate is available in iOS 4.0 and later. */



#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000

   @interface SendMoneyResponseVC : UITableViewController 
    <UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,    
    MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> 

   #else

   @interface SendMoneyResponseVC : UITableViewController 
    <UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
    MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> 

    #endif 

{
    IBOutlet UITableView *sendMoneyTableVC;

    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *refNumRemittanceCell;
    IBOutlet UILabel *refNumLabel, *refNumValueLabel, *refNumInfoLabel;

    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *refNumDomesticCell;
    IBOutlet UILabel *domesticInfoLabel, *feeAndReferenceLabel;

    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *shareRefNumCell;
    IBOutlet UIButton *shareRefNumButton;

    NSString *referenceNumber, *recipient, *currency, *mtoName;
    float amount, fee;
    int sendMoneyType;

    UIAlertView *smsAlertView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *sendMoneyTableVC;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *refNumRemittanceCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *refNumLabel, *refNumValueLabel, *refNumInfoLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *refNumDomesticCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *domesticInfoLabel, *feeAndReferenceLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *shareRefNumCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *shareRefNumButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *referenceNumber, *recipient, *currency, *mtoName;
@property float amount, fee;
@property int sendMoneyType;

- (IBAction) didPressShareButton;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the reason for doing this? Unless you want to compile with an outdated SDK you should get rid of this.

Interface Builder doesn't preprocess your files, so it will see two @interfaces and one @end.
And interface builder can't parse something like this.

Comment: That's right. I have tested my code with XCode 3.1.2. To compile with old SDK I needed to add this preprocessor. I know its not needed for latest xcode. But looking for any workaround to avoid IB warning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restructuring your code in a way which is equivalent to the compiler, but is less likely to confuse Interface Builder?  Something like this:

```
@interface SendMoneyResponseVC : UITableViewController 
    <UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
    MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,    
#endif 
    MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, 
    UIActionSheetDelegate> 
{ ... }
@end
```

This way there will be only one `@interface`/`@end` pair.